# MVT: Let $P(x)$ is a polynomial of $n$ degree and $P(x)=0$ has $n$ roots. Prove that $P(x)+P'(x)=0$ has at least $n$ roots.

Tags: calculus

Let $P(x)$ is a polynomial of $n$ degree and $P(x)=0$ has $n$ roots. Prove that $P(x)+P'(x)=0$ has at least $n$ roots.

**My idea**:
Let $g(x)=e^{x}P(x)$ and $g'(x)=e^{x}(P(x)+P'(x))$.
Because $g(x)=0$ has $n$ roots so $g'(x)=0$ has at least $n-1$ roots, which means $P(x)+P'(x)=0$ has at least $n-1$ roots . However the problem need $P(x)+P'(x)=0$ has at least $n$ roots.

Please correct me where I was wrong.

---

From the problem above, I think the problem I mention below has some connections:

Let $ax^{2}+bx+c=0, a\neq0$ has two real roots, $P(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficient and has $3$ real roots. Prove that $T(x)= aP(x)+bP'(x)+cP''(x)=0$ has at least $3$ real roots.

I do not know why we need the equation: $ax^{2}+bx+c=0$, so I do not have any ideas to prove the problem. Please help me!

Thank you so much!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have just edited it. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

$Q=P + P^\prime$ has at least $n-1$ roots and is of degree $n$ as $P$. Therefore is has $n$ roots as you can write

$$Q(x)=P(x) + P^\prime(x) = a(x-r_1) \dots (x-r_{n-1})q(x)$$ where $r_1, \dots r_{n-1}$ are the $n-1$ roots of $P + P^\prime$ and $q$ a polynomial of degree $1$. Therefore $Q$ has only real roots.

Let's prove that those are distinct.

By hypothesis $g$ has $n$ real roots $g_1 < \dots < g_n$. Therefore $Q$ has $n-1$ distinct roots in $(g_1,g_n)$. Now $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} g(x) = g(g_1)=0$. Hence the differentiable map $g$ attains its extremum at $g_{n+1} \in (-\infty, g_1)$. And we have $g^\prime(g_{n+1})=Q(g_{n+1})=0$. Finally proving that $Q$ has $n$ distinct real roots.

Comment: You do not, a priori, know that the root of $q$ is distinct from all the $r_i$. That's the _difficult_ part of this problem.

Comment: @Arthur Good comment. Answer updated to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

IF $P(x)=0$ is ral polynomial of degree $n$ and it has $n$ real roots,
then by Rolle's theorem:$\frac{d}{dx} (e^x P(x))= e^x[(P(x)+P'(x)]=0$ will have at least $n-1$ real roots. Since the degree of $P(x)+P'(x)$ remains $n$ so it will have $n$ real roots, namely the last unpaired root has to be real as the polynomial is real.

Note: the reality of the roots is most important here.

Comment: $P(x)+P'(x)$ could have a multiple root, like $x^2$ (second degree, yet only one double root). You have done nothing to address this possible complication.